# How to authorize swagger ui using JWT Bearer Authorization in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using JWT Authorization. Facing Issue on authorize using Jwt Bearer Authorization.

I want to Use swagger for my ClassBased(APIView) to list my used api's.
But It is not working. Without login Permission functions are showing in swagger API list. But API's with permission allowed is not showing. For this I have to Authorize the swagger using JWT access token. But it is not working. I am getting this below image for login with username & password. Also api_key. I tried using both api_key, but not working.

[image]

Comment: Can you help me to solve this issue? @aminography